# How does $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}} \sum\limits_{j=i}^{n-i} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{j} 1$ equal $\frac{n^3}{8}$?

Tags: summation

I'm trying to understand how to simplify summations. My text says that: $$\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}} \sum_{j=i}^{n-i} \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1 = \frac{n^3}{8}$$

But does not explain how to get to the right-hand side.

I think the above nested summation evaluates to $\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \left[\sum_{j=i}^{n-i} j = i + (i + 1) + (i + 2) + .. + (n-i-1) + (n-i)\right]$, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\sum_{j=i}^{n-i} j = \sum_{j=1}^{n-i} j - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} j.$$
The right hand side now should look rather familiar (Gauss...).

There is also a rule for 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2,$$
if you look this up and prove it or if you already know it, that should give the final result.

Comment: I think I need to brush up on how to manipulate and split summations and do more practice problems. Can you recommend me a book or something that explains this particular topic very well?

Answer (score 1):

Exploit the symmetry.

Put $n=2m$ (assuming $n$ is even):

$$\begin{align}
S
=\sum_{i=1}^{\frac n2}\sum_{j=i}^{n-i}\sum_{k=1}^j 1
=\sum_{i=1}^{\frac n2}\sum_{j=i}^{n-i}j
&=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=i}^{2m-i}j&&(n=2m)\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=i}^{2m-i}(2m-j)&&(j\leftarrow 2m-j)\tag{2}\\
&=m\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=i}^{2m-i}1
&&\dfrac{(1)+(2)}2\\
&=m\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=i}^m1+\sum_{j=m+1}^{2m-i}1\right)\\
&=m\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=i}^m1+\sum_{j=1}^{m-i}1\right)\\
&=m\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=i}^m1+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}1\right)
&&\big(i\leftarrow m-i+1\atop\scriptsize\text{for second summation}\big)\\
&=m\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^m 1\\
&=m^3\\
&=\color{red}{\frac {n^3}{8\;}}
\end{align}$$

The solution is derived only by manipulating summation limits and indices without requiring expansion or evaluation of sum of squares or integers.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
  \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1 &= j \\
  \sum_{j=i}^{n-i} j
  &= \frac{n(n-2i+1)}{2} \\
  S &= \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \frac{n(n-2i+1)}{2} \\
  &= \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} 1-
     n \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} i
\end{align}

- If $n=2m$,
  \begin{align}
    S &= \frac{2m(2m+1)}{2} \times m-2m\times \frac{m(m+1)}{2} \\
    &= m^3 \\
    &= \frac{n^3}{8}
  \end{align}
- If $n=2m-1$,
  \begin{align}
    S &= \frac{(2m-1)(2m)}{2} \times (m-1)-(2m-1)\times \frac{(m-1)m}{2} \\
    &= \left( \frac{2m-1}{2} \right)^3-\frac{2m-1}{8} \\
    &= \frac{n^3-n}{8}
  \end{align}

> Your equality holds for even $n$ only.